# Giving an advancement on crafting a recipe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I have a datapack and in the datapack is a custom crafting recipe. In the advancements folder, I have created an advancement which should trigger when I craft the recipe. However if I craft the item I don't see anything happening. What have I done wrong.

```
data/
├─ enchanted_dyes/
│  ├─ advancements/
│  │  ├─ magenta_bow_1.json
│  ├─ functions/
│  │  ├─ magenta_bow_1.mcfunction
│  ├─ recipes/
│  │  ├─ magenta_bow_1.json/
```

This is my advancement file.

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "Unlocked": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:recipe_unlocked",
            "conditions": {
                "recipe": "enchanted_dyes:magenta_bow_1"
            }
        }
    },
    "rewards": {
        "function": "enchanted_dyes:magenta_bow_1"
    }
}
```

And this is the function I am calling in the advancement.

```
tell @a "Hello World"
```